# C# MonoGame - backwards player movement

Tags: c#, monogame, game-development

I'm working on a school project, in which I'm making an astroids clone.
I've been working on player movement and have implemented the code below.

I'm getting some weird behavior when trying to move the player sprite backward and I'm having a hard time understanding the math behind it.

I've commented below where the problem is

position = velocity + position;

```
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) rotation -= 0.1f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) rotation += 0.1f;

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            velocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
            velocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;

        }

        //this is where I need help

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            velocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(rotation) - tangentialVelocity;
            velocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rotation) - tangentialVelocity;

        }
        else if (velocity != Vector2.Zero)
        {
            float i = velocity.X;
            float j = velocity.Y;

            velocity.X = i -= friction * i;
            velocity.Y = j -= friction * j;

        }
```

Comment: Please call `Keyboard.GetState()` only once per step.

Comment: @Strom If you have time can you elaborate on where I call it more than once, and why I shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like the logic for forwards/backwards thrust should be as follows:

Given some variable like `int thrustPower = 1.0f;`

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
{
    velocity.X += (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * thrustPower;
    velocity.Y += (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * thrustPower;
}

if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
{
    velocity.X -= (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * thrustPower;
    velocity.Y -= (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * thrustPower;
}
```

So that if either `Keys.Up` or `Keys.Down` is pressed, the velocity on each axis will scale by the normal amount of `ThrustPower` projected onto that axis.

This also gets around the problem of having to deal with what you call `tangentialVelocity`, but I assume should actually be `radialVelocity` or just `speed`.